# c++: is it better to have a global variable or create a local variable?

Tags: c++

for example i have a library function which needs to be used for validating signatures,and is only called when requested.

lets say i have a library class to verify signature
sigverify.hpp

```
class SigVerify
{
bool verifySignature(std::string path);
}
```

sigverify.cpp

```
bool Sigverify::verifySignature(std::string path)
{
 //verfies signature
 return true;
}
```

now assume that i compiled sigverify as library and linked it to my main service code
Service.hpp

```
#include "sigverify.hpp"
class SeviceClass
{
 public:
 void makeLibCall();
 //is it better to declare a variable here and use it in my cpp
   SigVerify m_sigVerify;
 }
```

Service.cpp

```
void ServiceClass::makeLibCall()
{
 // OR declare a local variable here like this
   Sigverify m_sigVerify;
   bool result = m_sigVerify.verifySignautre(path);
}
```

the library call is only made in one place in my entire code, so i think it is better to create a local variable when there is a need to make the call?
which is better in terms of performance??please help me :)

Comment: Why have an object at all?  You can either make `verifySignautre` `static` so you don't even need an object to call it with our you can just make it a free standing function and get rid of the class entirely.

Comment: sadly i cant change the library code, apparently there are other services which are using the library code, so i wont be able to make changes there

Comment: It should depend on what the function does. If the class does some costy initialization on being constructed, constructing once as global variable may be better. If it is important to initialize every time before calling the function, local variable may be better. Another choice is declaring the function as static to eliminate the dependency to an instance if it doesn't require any status stored in the class.

Comment: Yet another choice: static local variable

Comment: @MikeCAT thanks understood a little better, apart from this in terms of space consumed on the stack and heap can you comment on that if you have any idea

Comment: If the function needs to open a file (which seems to be the case given the `path` parameter), then performance difference of local vs global will be negligible compared to that (unless the class construction is very expensive).

Comment: which is better in terms of performance depends on details you didnt include in the question. Eg how expensive is it to create the object? Does it have a constructor that does something? Eventually you need to measure if you care about performance. On the other hand, does perforamnce matter in the first place? If I can trade a global variable for 1 or 2 cpu cycles in non performance critical code I'd definitely go for it

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number the constructor is like this
SigVerify() = default; so i guess it doesn't do anything complex right?

Comment: depends on what members the class has. The code you posted is obviously not the real class (the method is private)

Comment: Quantify "better" and write a program that measures this.  Then try both ways and measure what is better.

Comment: If `SigVerify` has no data members (as your example implies), there's no difference between any of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a third option mentioned in comments:

```
void ServiceClass::makeLibCall()
{
   static Sigverify m_sigVerify;
   bool result = m_sigVerify.verifySignautre(path);
}
```

`m_sigVerify` will be initialized once, when the function is called for the first time.

However, to know what is more performant you need to measure. There is no way around that. If the class is really not more than what you posted, then creating an object and calling a function can be expected to be not be more expensive than just calling the function. To be sure: measure.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your inputs, it helped me have a better understanding, sorry i couldn't post the real class i'm sure i would have gotten better insights if i did so.
will be accepting 463035818_i_not_a_number answer.

Comment: @VamsiKaredla fyi, you do not need to post the "real code". Often thats not possible because its either too much or you do not want to disclose confidential information. But you could have posted a [mcve], some example that is close enough to the real code so you can apply the answer to your real case

Comment: thanks for the info, this is only my second question here, i will definetly note your point.
thanks a lot :)

Comment: Keep in mind, that a static variable like this introduces global state. If there are several instances of the `ServiceClass` that maybe run in different threads, you have to be extra careful to not introduce a race condition with this kind if code. Of course it might be safe depending on what exactly `verfiySignature()` does.